# Java does javax.swing.Timer run on new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

I am using javax.swing.Timer to schedule and run events. But it seems to be freezing the GUI. Just wanted to know whether these events are run on a seperate thread or whether I have to do it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Although all Timers perform their waiting using a single, shared thread (created by the first Timer object that executes), the action event handlers for Timers execute on another thread -- the event-dispatching thread. This means that the action handlers for Timers can safely perform operations on Swing components. However, it also means that the handlers *must execute quickly* to keep the GUI responsive."—[`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

<sup>Emphasis added.</sup>

Addendum: [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) was designed for  just this scenario. In particular, it offers a convenient way to offload work while periodically reporing progress on the EDT.