# Java javax.swing.Timer - freezing my GUI. Solution?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a task running using javax.swing.Timer. It executes once every few minutes. The task takes a second or two, and it is freezing my GUI.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: could you post code where timer is created and the task itself?

Comment: Is the task freezing your GUI for the second or two that the Timer task takes to execute, or is it completely locking up your application?

Comment: It is just hanging for 2 seconds, then all is good.. Should I initiate the SwingWorker on the Timer callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer tasks are executed on the Event Dispatching thread so while your task is running, no other swing event can happen and your gui will freeze. You should make a separate thread for such a long task or use SwingWorker.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490362/java-does-javax-swing-timer-run-on-new-thread) question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The task may be taking more that 2 seconds.. Does the task require access to GUI? If not use separate thread. The specific part of the task which require GUI access, can use SwingWorker to update the GUI.