# JOptionPane doesn't work correct in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, joptionpane

In my game, when I create a JOptionalPane, after I click on the "Ok" button, it draws the dialog over the panel. Below are pictures of the error.

JOptionPane before the error:

[image]

JOptionPane after the error, after click on the button "Yes"

[image]

The JOptionPane is created from class who extends from JComponent, in this line of code:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent().getParent(),
        "The end! Lifes = 0");
```

Comment: APerson241,A--C, thank you very much!

Comment: JOptionPane is functioning well, but you've a bug elsewhere in your code, perhaps in how you're drawing your graphics/painting the JPanel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your panel's implementation of `paintComponent()` fails to invoke `super.paintComponent()`, as shown in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213178/230513).

Comment: Thank you very much! After creating JOptionPane I called repaint() and now after click on "Yes" the JOptionPane draws over panel and quickly remove