# Odd repaint functionality

Tags: java, swing, repaint

**Brief description of Program**

Hi guys. I got bored this morning and decided to write a graphing program. Eventually i'll be able to run things like *Dijksta's Algorithm* on this software.

When anything changes on screen, a call to the `repaint` method of the `JPanel` where everything is painted to is made. This is the `JPanel` paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    for(Node node : graph.getNodes()){
        node.paint(g);
    }

    for(Link link : graph.getLinks()){
        link.paint(g);
    }
}
```

It simply cycles through each element in the lists, and paints them.

The paint method for the node class is:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(color);
    g.drawOval(location.x, location.y, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(name, location.x + 20, location.y + 20);
}
```

And for the link it is:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Point p1 = node1.getLocation();
    Point p2 = node2.getLocation();
    // Grab the two nodes from the link.
    g.drawLine(p1.x + 20, p1.y + 20, p2.x + 20, p2.y + 20);
    // Draw the line between them.
    int midPointX = ((p1.x + p2.x) / 2) + (100 / (p2.x - p1.x));
    int midPointY = ((p1.y + p2.y) / 2) + 30;
    // Compute the mid point of the line and get it closer to the line.
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(weight), midPointX, midPointY);
}
```

**The Problem**

The issue I am having arises when I use the `JOptionPane` class. When I select the option to add a new node, and select where to place it, an `inputDialog` pops up, asking for the node's name.

The nodes are added fine, for this behaviour occurs:

[image]
    Is this a common problem; an issue with `paint` or `repaint` perhaps?

Nonetheless, here is the code that calls the `inputDialog`:

```
Function addNode = functionFac.getInstance(state);
                String name = "";
                while(!name.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
                    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the name of the node.", null);
                }

                addNode.execute(stage, new NodeMessage(arg0.getPoint(), name));
```

*PS*: Function is an interface type that I have written.

Comment: +1 for a thorough examination of the uncommon presentation of a common problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

"If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts."—[`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213178/230513) that examines a related issue.

Comment: Ah Excellent! I simply renamed `paint` to `paintComponent` and called `super.paintComponent` and it's removed the issue entirely. Nice answer, thank you for the links :) +1!

Comment: Also, the Graphics context is shared during a paint process, so you are likely to have what ever the previous component painted still within the Graphics. One of the jobs paintComponent does is to prepare the component painting

Comment: For reference, @MadProgrammer has addressed similar anomalies using the term ["paint chain"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+%22paint+chain%22).