# A nested JPanel's background image is not re-drawn correctly

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I used `ImageIO.read` to get image (`BackgroundImage`) and painted the background image like this :

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);        
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, backDim.width, backDim.height, null);
}
```

and I added some component on that `JPanel` (background color of the panels inserted into it is `new Color(0,0,0,0)` (Transparent).
The background image is shown correctly when started; however, when I drag it to the bottom edge of the screen, half of them is erased. When I drag it to the left or right edge of the screen, it is re-drawn.

Ahh, and when I removed the `Box.createRigidArea()` gap, only the background of the titles are shown correctly. Other space is just the default color of a JPanel (light-gray).

**EDIT**: I added a component listener to make the screen drawn every time I move the window, but it calles repaint frequently so the computer might be overloaded. Is there any other solutions?

**EDIT**: The problem is that some (or most) of the drawn image is erased when I move the window (which contains the nested `JPanel` with a background image) to the bottom of the screen and drag it back. However, the `repaint()` is not called.

**Final edit**: *Solved.* It was because I did not call setOpaque(false);

Comment: `however, when I drag it to the bottom edge of the screen, half of them is erased. When I drag it to the left or right edge of the screen, it is re-drawn.` == no idea whats happens, is this JPanel in JScrollPane, for better hepl sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with image sticked into this question or by generating [BufferedImage on fly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)

Comment: Please edit your code and question to match your current problem, it's currently impossible to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @jinoh67 no one from edits to help somehow, in guessing statuses still, you issue is in your code ..... :-),

Comment: @jinoh67 : I see a slight flaw in code, i.e. the use of null as `ImageObserver` (`g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, backDim.width, backDim.height, null);`), which in this case needs to be `g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, backDim.width, backDim.height, this);`

Comment: @nIcEcOw Ah, yes. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> background color of the panels inserted into it is new Color(0,0,0,0)
>   (Transparent)

A JPanel's opacity is true by default. If you set a transparent background color, you need to set the opacity to false - otherwise you will get painting artefacts (as you experienced)

```
panel.setBackground(transparentColor);
panel.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: +1 jinoh67: See also this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7213178/230513).