# Swing JScrollPane Overflow

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have a Java Swing application with lots of custom components. The layout is a large JScrollPane that contains a JPanel, which has several panels in a BoxLayout from left to right.

In the image below, the code panel contains a JScrollPane that contains another panel that draws its text. This is all custom, no JTextArea/JTextView/Whatever.

I'm stumped by the effect I'm getting below. It seems as though whatever "tween" is being drawn on is either not opaque, or isn't being re-drawn at the right time. I've tried everything I can, but had no luck fixing things. The code drawing the text is very simple - uses Graphics2D and g2.drawString(...).

[image]

Comment: And? What is the question?

Comment: no help possible without SSCCE

Comment: The question is, how is this possible? How can something drawn in a jpanel end up being drawn on a component of its parents parents parent?

Comment: `It seems as though whatever "tween" is being drawn on is either not opaque,` sounds like a good guess to me.

Answer (score 1):

The [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) API notes that, "If you do not honor the [*opaque property*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#props) you will likely see visual artifacts." A typical example that violates this principle is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213178/230513). The effect usually stems from displaying a buffered remnant that you've told Swing should *not* need repainting. In particular,

> One of the most common mistakes component implementations make is that they allow the opaque property to default to `true`, yet they do not completely render the area defined by their bounds, the result is occasional screen garbage in the unrendered areas.