# Paint program in Java. JPanel Refreshes badly

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

Hello guys I have few questions regarding program:
First of all I ve made 2 JPanels and added them to main Window with BorderLayout Center and East. [image: Error 1]

Program looks like that but when I start to draw something my Menu appears on Center Border Layout dont know to be honest why.

[image: Error 2]

Additionaly when I minimalize or change the Window size the graphic dissapears: /.

[image: Error 3]

Third thing I can only draw a polygonal line ("Łamana") and again I dont know how to make it draw a simple line ("Prosta"). Atm Prosta is same as Łamana.

Additionaly sometimes it draws me few shapes ("Koło") - circle for example.

My code:

Main

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class edytor extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static String jaki, co = null;
public static int jak, jak1;

final static float dash1[] = { 10.0f };
final static BasicStroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1.0f,
        BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.0f, dash1, 0.0f);

public edytor() throws HeadlessException {
    super("PAINT");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(840, 702);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    jak = 10;
    co = "Łamana";
    jaki = "Czarny";

    JButton zapis = new JButton("Zapis");

    zapis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    JPanel prawyPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 0));
    JPanel lewyPanel = new rysowanie();
    lewyPanel.setVisible(true);
    prawyPanel.setVisible(true);

    final JComboBox<String> coRysujemy = new JComboBox<String>();
    coRysujemy.setEditable(true);
    coRysujemy.addItem("Łamana");
    coRysujemy.addItem("Kwadrat");
    coRysujemy.addItem("Koło");
    coRysujemy.addItem("Prosta");

    prawyPanel.add(coRysujemy);

    coRysujemy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            co = (String) coRysujemy.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });

    final JComboBox<String> jakiKolor = new JComboBox<String>();
    jakiKolor.setEditable(true);
    jakiKolor.addItem("Czarny");
    jakiKolor.addItem("Niebieski");
    jakiKolor.addItem("Zielony");
    prawyPanel.add(jakiKolor);

    jakiKolor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            jaki = (String) jakiKolor.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });

    final JComboBox<String> jakGrube = new JComboBox<String>();
    jakGrube.setEditable(true);
    jakGrube.addItem("10");
    jakGrube.addItem("20");
    jakGrube.addItem("30");
    prawyPanel.add(jakGrube);

    jakGrube.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jak = jakGrube.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    });

    final JComboBox<String> jakRysowane = new JComboBox<String>();
    jakRysowane.setEditable(true);
    jakRysowane.addItem("Nie Przerywane");
    jakRysowane.addItem("Przerywane");
    prawyPanel.add(jakRysowane);
    prawyPanel.add(zapis);
    lewyPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(lewyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(prawyPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    jakRysowane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jak1 = jakRysowane.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    edytor ramka = new edytor();
    ramka.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Drawing Window Panel

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class rysowanie extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 636480153152364773L;
private int squareX;
private int squareY;
private int squareW;
private int squareH;
private int xstart, ystart, xend, yend;

public rysowanie() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (edytor.jak == 1) {
        edytor.jak = 10;
    }
    if (edytor.jak == 2) {
        edytor.jak = 20;
    }

    if (edytor.jak == 3) {
        edytor.jak = 30;
    }

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            squareX = e.getX();
            squareY = e.getY();
            repaint();

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getX() > squareX)
                squareW = e.getX() - squareX;
            else {
                squareW = squareX - e.getX();
                squareX = e.getX();
            }
            if (e.getY() > squareY)
                squareH = e.getY() - squareY;
            else {
                squareH = squareY - e.getY();
                squareY = e.getY();
            }
            repaint();
        }

    });

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            xstart = e.getX();
            ystart = e.getY();
            repaint();

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            xend = e.getX();
            yend = e.getY();
            repaint();

        }

    });

    if (edytor.co == "Kwadrat") {
        if (edytor.jaki == "Niebieski") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        }
        if (edytor.co == "Czarny") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Zielony") {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        }
    }

    if (edytor.co == "Łamana") {
        if (edytor.jaki == "Niebieski") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g2.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Czarny") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Zielony") {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
    }

    if (edytor.co == "Koło") {
        if (edytor.jaki == "Niebieski") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawOval(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Czarny") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawOval(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Zielony") {
            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g2.drawOval(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
        }
    }

    if (edytor.co == "Prosta") {

        if (edytor.jaki == "Niebieski") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g2.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Czarny") {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
        if (edytor.jaki == "Zielony") {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(edytor.jak));
            if (edytor.jak1 == 1) {
                g2.setStroke(edytor.dashed);
            }
            g.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Would love any hints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPanel repaint issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213178/jpanel-repaint-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you break the paint chain by not calling `super.paint()` in the `paint` method. What you are seeing are the weird paint artifacts left over from not clearing the paint area (done by calling `super.paint()`)

Rather than overriding `paint()`, you should instead be override `paintComponent`.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Note: When you *do* call `super.paint[Component]`, that will also clear the previous line drawn, which is probably not the functionality you want. You have a few options around this:

- You could create a `List` of `Point2D` object, add points to the list and iterate though the list in the `paintComponent` method to draw lines from point to point.
- You could draw each line to a `BufferedImage` and draw the image in the `paintComponent` method.

---

Also don't compare strings with `==`. Use `eqauls()`. Google `How do I compare Strings in Java`

---

For future reference, this site is not a help desk and you should not expect users/answerers to help you debug a bunch of different problems. You should ask one specific question regarding one specific problem. If you have multiple problems, then break the question in to different posts.